# Python - Remove ending of words based on list of endings

Tags: python

I want to remove ending of words if the ending of the word is like any of the possible endings in the given list. I used the below code:

```
ending = ('os','o','as','a')

def rchop(thestring):
  if thestring.endswith((ending)):
    return thestring[:-len((ending))]
  return thestring

rchop('potatos')
```

The result is: 'pot'. 
But I want this: 'potat'

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were slicing the string by then length of the ending's tuple (4 elements). That's why the you received the wrong string.

```
endings = ('os','o','as','a')

def rchop(thestring):
    for ending in endings:
        if thestring.endswith(ending):
            return thestring[:-len(ending)]
    return thestring

print(rchop('potatos'))
```

Returns:

```
potat
```

Comment: You are faster than i am

Answer (score 3):

You can try `re`.

```
import re
x="potatos"
print re.sub(r"(?:os|as|a|o)$","",x)
```

Output: `potat`.

`|` means `or` here and `$` means `end of string`

Answer (score 0):

Or try this (very short), (note, even works when non of `ending` elements are at the end of the string):

```
def f(s):
    s2=next((i for i in ending if s.endswith(i)),'')
    return s[:len(s)-len(s2)]
```

Now:

```
print(f('potatos'))
```

Is:

```
potat
```

It's as expected!!!